# Connecting to Amazon Aurora with AWS IAM DB authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, identity, amazon-iam

I know that with Amazon Aurora MySQL, we can authenticate to the DB instance or DB cluster using AWS IAM database authentication. I followed the instructions [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam/) and It is working as instructed. However, this solution still needs the AWS credentials to be stored on the EC2 instance. I thought the whole purpose of this is to use the IAM roles to manage temporary credentials for applications running on an EC2 instance, so that we do not have to distribute long-term credentials (such as a user name and password or access keys) to an EC2 instance. Is there any way to connect to Amazon Aurora MySQL with an IAM role which does not need the AWS credentials to be directly stored within the EC2 instance?

Here are some screenshots:

**~/.aws/credentials:**
[image]

Can connect to the DB instance:
[image]

Comment the aws credentials:
[image]

Now can't connect to the DB instance:
[image]

Here is the policies attached to the EC2 Role:
[image]

And, here is the policy "AmazonAuroraDBConnectAccess":
[image]

The username is created by:

```
create user usuarioiam IDENTIFIED WITH AWSAuthenticationPlugin as 'RDS';
```

Also ran `aws sts get-caller-identity`. The expected IAM EC2 role is being used:
[image]

Comment: Lol, this link is included in my question; I followed all the instructions there and it's working. Have no issues with that. But, this solution needs the AWS credentials to be stored on the EC2 instance to generate the authentication token (which is used instead of password). Based on AWS best practices (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html) we should not store AWS credentials onto EC2 instances. Instead, define an IAM role that has appropriate permissions for our application and launch the Amazon EC2 instance with roles for EC2.

Comment: @Malgi, this does **not** require storing credentials on the instance, and it isn't clear why you are under the impression that it does.  If you do not configure aws-cli with a key and secret, it automatically uses the IAM instance role credentials.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Have you done this before? I will update my question with some screenshots of why I am saying this requires AWS creds stored onto the EC2 instance.

Comment: Yes, I have done this, using the instance's IAM role.  The most likely explanation is that your IAM role does not have the necessary policy statements to allow access... or you granted the role the correct permissions, but did not wait long enough for them to take effect.  Changes to role policies for EC2 instance roles can sometimes require a few minutes before they start working.

Comment: Since a token generated using a role has a slightly different structure than one generated with an access key and secret, another possibility here is that you have an edge case where you need to supply `--password="$TOKEN"` for the shell to correctly handle your token.  [*"When referencing a variable, it is generally advisable to enclose its name in double quotes."*](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)

Comment: nope, enclosing it with double quotes did not fix the issue. I also waited so long for the role to get affected. I might have attached incorrect roles and policies to the EC2 instance, going to add the policies and roles to my question.

Comment: Use `aws sts get-caller-identity` to verify that aws-cli is actually using the credentials that you expect it to be using.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot ran that command and verified it's using that IAM EC2 role. See the update to my question.

Comment: And you have only one Aurora instance in your cluster?  For a cluster with multiple nodes, your ARN should be (e.g.) `...:dbuser:cluster-CO4FHMOYDKJ7CVBEJS2UWDQX7I/jane_doe` but if you have only one instance then `db-xxxx` is fine.  I assume you used exactly the same policy for the IAM user?  How long ago did you set up this role policy, and attach it to the role?

Comment: Awesome. That was the reason! I changed it to `...:dbuser:cluster-CO4FHMOYDKJ7CVBEJS2UWDQX7I/jane_doe` and it got fixed. Thank you so much. You have made my day.